# String resource not found while testing App on emulator

Tags: android, string, resources, emulation

Yesterday i tried to test my app on a emulated device.

The App start's correctly but it seems like if some String resources can't be found because it stops on a string resource not found exception!?

When I launch the app on a real device all works perfectly but on a emulated device I got the message that some string resources can't be found although it's shown at the file R.java.

Research doesn't helped me because all they said is "clean your project", "rebuilt your app", "delete app on emulator and redeploy it" but none of this works!
It's confusing because this behavior doesn't occur on all string resources! Some are found, some not!

Is this behavior known by anyone and haven't I just googled the correct question???

***Example***:

**string.xml** (in folder values) (*summary*)

```
<string name="text_str_three">Text Three</string>
```

**Activity :** (*summary*)

```
final String str_1 = getResources().getString(R.string.text_str_one);
final String str_2 = getResources().getString(R.string.text_str_two);   
final String str_3 = getResources().getString(R.string.text_str_three);
```

**R.java :** (*summary*)

```
public static final int text_str_three=0x7f070077;
```

**Logcat :** (*summary*)

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070077
```

'**text_str_one**' and '**text_str_two**' are found, but '**text_str_three**' not, why?

Comment: Are you using different resource directories ? like values-v11, values-sw600dp, values-land, etc ?

Comment: Can you put some code, that might help for better understanding.